# Adjusting CSV data: appending cells to previous row, merge cells containing certain string

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a file, *data.csv*, that looks like this (two columns; A and B):

```
A       B
01      a
        'b'
0101    a
        b
010101  a
        'b'
        'c'
        d
        'e'
        f
010102  a
        b
        'd'
        'e'
010201  a
        b
        'c'
        d

02      a
        b
0201    a
        b

020101  a
        b
        'd'
        'e'
020102  a
        'b'
        c
020201  a
        b
        c
        d
        'e'
020301  a
        'b'
        c
        d
```

I want it to look like this (five columns; A, B, C, D and E):

```
A       B   C   D   E
01      a   b       
0101    a   b       
010101  a   b   c   d, e, f
010102  a   b       d, e
010201  a   b   c   d
02      a           
0201    a   b       
020101  a   b       d, e
020102  a   b   c   
020201  a   b   c   d, e
020301  a   b   c   d
```

This is what I know about *data.csv*:

- UTF-8 encoding
- UNIX style end-of-line
- Tabulator delimiter
- Some *rows* are blank (empty *cells*)
- Some *rows* begin with an empty *cell* (a tabulator)
- Some *rows* begin with two, four or six digits
- Some *cells* contain text strings, here represented by a single character
- Some of the text strings are surrounded by ' signs
- The 'a', 'b' and 'c' values can not be assumed to always be present
- There is no pattern for 'a', 'b' or 'c'
- There is a pattern for 'd', 'e' and 'f' - the word `foo` is part of their strings

Treating *data.csv* as a text file I put together a script to:

- Delete empty lines
- Append lines beginning with a tab character (an empty cell) to the previous line
- Remove the ' signs

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
f = open('data.csv')
c = f.read()
f.close()
c = c.replace('\n\n', '\n')
c = c.replace('\n\t', '\t')
c = c.replace("'", "")
f = open('output.csv', 'w')
f.write(c)
f.close()
```

...and then I got stuck. Perhaps there's a more uniform way to do this along with the other adjustments, using the `csv` module. How can I solve this with Python 3.3 (I assume any 3.x solution will be compatible)?

**Update**

Based on Martijn Pieter's answer I came up with this, and it *seems* to be working, although I'm not sure that the 'a', 'b' and 'c' text values are always put in the appropriate columns. Also, the last row is skipped/left blank.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    write_this_row = None
    for row in reader:
        # If there is a row with content...
        if row:
            # If the first cell has content...
            if row[0]:
                if write_this_row != None:
                    writer.writerow(write_this_row)
                write_this_row = row
            elif 'foo' in row[1]:
                if len(write_this_row) < 5:
                    write_this_row.extend([''] * (5 - len(row)))
                if write_this_row[4]:
                    write_this_row[4] += ';' + row[1]
                else:
                    write_this_row[4] = row[1]
            else:
                write_this_row.insert(3, row[1])
```

Comment: I'm not so sure regex has anything to do with this anymore, I may have underestimated the `csv` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `csv` module to read the data, massage this per row, and write it out again.

You can create 'empty' columns by using `None` or an empty string `''` as the value for that column. Vice-versa, reading empty columns (so between consecutive tabs) gives you empty strings.

```
with open('input.csv', newline='') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')

    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 3:
            # detect if `c` is missing (insert your own test here)
            # sample test looks for 3 consecutive columns with values f, o and o
            if row[3:6] == ['f', 'o', 'o']
                # insert an empty `c`
                row.insert(3, '')

        if len(row) < 5:
            # make row at least 5 columns long
            row.extend([''] * (5 - len(row)))
        if len(row) > 5:
            # merge any excess columns into the 5th column
            row[4] = ','.join(row[4:])
            del row[5:]

        writer.writerow(row)
```

**Update:**

Instead of using a flag, use the reader as an iterator (calling `next()` on it to get the next row instead of using a `for` loop):

```
with open('input.csv', newline='') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')

    row = None

    try:
        next(reader)  # skip the `A   B` headers.

        line = next(reader)  # prime our loop
        while True:
            while not line[0]:
                # advance to the first line with a column 0 value
                line = next(reader)

            row = line  # start off with the first number and column
            line = next(reader)  # prime the subsequent lines loop

            while line and not line[0]:
                # process subsequent lines until we find one with a value in col 0 again
                cell = line[1]
                if cell == 'foo':    # detect column d
                    row.append('')   # and insert empty value
                row.append(cell)
                line = next(reader)

            # consolidate, write
            if len(row) < 5:
                # make row at least 5 columns long
                row.extend([''] * (5 - len(row)))
            if len(row) > 5:
                # merge any excess columns into the 5th column
                row[4] = ','.join(row[4:])
                del row[5:]

            writer.writerow(row)
            row = None
    except StopIteration:
        # reader is done, no more lines to come
        # process the last row if there was one
        if row is not None:
            # consolidate, write
            if len(row) < 5:
                # make row at least 5 columns long
                row.extend([''] * (5 - len(row)))
            if len(row) > 5:
                # merge any excess columns into the 5th column
                row[4] = ','.join(row[4:])
                del row[5:]

            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Interesting, but `while line and not line[0]:` doesn't make any sense to me, at the first time at this point `line` will be `['01', 'a']` - resulting in `line` being `true` and `not line[0]` being `false`. It'll then move on to `if len(row) < 5:` and go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Right, I forgot one `line = next(reader)` line there.  Fixed that.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! During processing subsequent lines it will crash upon coming across an empty line. It seems to me that the `while line and not line[0]:` should catch that, but it doesn't. Instead, I get `IndexError: list index out of range` on `cell = line[1]`.

Comment: Looks like you have lines without tabs in that case.

Comment: Assuming I run some regex in advance on the input.csv to delete empty lines (I must have misunderstood an empty line to still count as a cell), remove ' characters and replace `d`, `e` and `f` with `foo` as well as for the sake of legibility replace all tabs with semi-colons and thus end up with the *input.csv* displayed [here](https://gist.github.com/totte/5969221). When then running your slightly altered code (to use semi-colons instead of tabs) I get the output displayed in output.csv. Curious! :)

Comment: I don't see a need to remove empty lines with a regular expression. Just detect and skip those in the `while` loop above.

Comment: The `csv` module will take care of any quoting (`'` characters); you may have to tweak the dialect a little, but it'll work fine.

Comment: @totte: but an input file like that helps; debugging my code now.. :-)

Comment: @totte: moved the `line = next(reader)` line to the end of the inner `while` loop, should all work correctly now. The empty values after each `foo` are of course due to the primitive `d` column test; you can always adjust that and / or move it to past the `while` loop to the section where we extend the row to at least 5 columns, etc.

Comment: @totte: Thanks; sometimes Chrome, when copying and pasting a line in the SO editor, will replace some spaces with non-breaking spaces instead and I fail to notice.

Comment: This question hasn't generated much interest, so I'm unsure as to if I should revise it yet again. As it turns out, I'm encountering all kinds of erratic data but I have, as of now, [working code](https://gist.github.com/totte/5977304) to deal with the current knowns. Included is sample input data (input.csv) based on my latest findings and the result (output.csv) from processing it. Thank you for your help, I'm not sure what you meant with "Instead of using a flag", an explanation on that and further criticism of my scripts is welcome. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really a debug service; let's keep this to one problem per post. If *this* problem has been solved but new problems have arisen, it is better to create a *new* question.

Comment: At first glance, you were using `write_this_row` as a flag var to keep track of when to write a new row.

Comment: Should I revise my question and your answer to use semi-colon delimiters for the sake of legibility? The samples I provided seem misleading. On another, personal, note, I found the following the important pieces of the answer to me: the `csv` module along with `while` loops (assembling the row to be written cell by cell) as well as list and string methods to handle unwanted whitespaces make for a nice(?) solution.

Comment: Glad you found that to be helpful. It should not matter for legibility if you use tabs or semicolons, really; but it's your question, your code, and if you feel you can communicate better about what you are trying to do then use semicolons by all means! :-)