# Get following lines when reading CSV into a list

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read from a tab delimited file in python formatted like this:

```
Things     Some things here spanning multiple lines 
but continues on to this line as well 
next_item     123456789
```

I use the following code to read in the file as a list of lists:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
     data = list(list(rec) for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t'))
```

The goal is to create a list of lists like this:

```
[['Things', 'Some things here spanning multiple lines but continues on to this line as well'], ['next_item', '123456789']
```

Problem is, this reads the second line into a list of its own.
I imagine this is a simple fix, I just don't know where to begin. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe check to see if the line only contains one item, and if it does, just append it to the second item in the previous list?

Comment: This idea sounds promising; I will poke around a bit and see if I can get it working.

Comment: split every list using `\t` and see if it splits into two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `regex` to do this. Effectively, you're looking for instances where there is a newline, followed by a line without tabs, followed immediately by a newline. using `re.sub` we can replace the first newline with a space - merging the text into the previous line. If we then split this using `re.split` to get all kinds of newlines, we can feed it into `csv.reader`:

```
import re
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

normalised_data = re.sub(r'[\n\r]+([^\t\n\r]+)([\n\r]+)', r' \g<1>\g<2>', data)

output_list = list(rec for rec in csv.reader(re.split(r'[\n\r]+', normalised_data), delimiter='\t'))

print output_list
```

This returns:

```
[['Things', 'Some things here spanning multiple lines but continues on to this line as well'], ['next_item', '123456789']]
```

As required.

Comment: Regex is a bit of an overkill for something so simple.

Comment: @zwer perhaps - I'm assuming it's a bit more complicated than OP's example, and I think this should extend reasonably.

Comment: @asongtoruin you're right, the example I gave was very simplified; regardless, the answer you gave worked perfectly for my situation.

Comment: @masterofdiscuise glad to be of help! If you're not familiar with using regexes, they're worth looking into for non-standard text analysis

Comment: @asongtoruin I have heard they are very beneficial, I will take a look today.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use `next()` to read lines and merge lines that don't contain your delimiter (in this case `'\t'`).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557181/adjusting-csv-data-appending-cells-to-previous-row-merge-cells-containing-cert) could give you pointers on implementation further

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to split by `\t` first, then by `\n`. That way we get a somewhat odd list with the keys at the end of the inner list, key and value indices  are off by one. The splitted multiline data is kept in lists and can be rejoined with linefeed or blank.

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    odd = [x.split('\n') for x in data.split('\t')]
    keys = [x[-1] for x in odd[:-1]]
    vals = [x[:-1] for x in odd[1:-1]] + [odd[-1]]
    lol = [[k,v] for k,v in zip(keys,[' '.join(x)for x in vals])]
```

---

Edit:

If you are willing to use regular expression you have the chance to lookahead to stop the match before the next record.

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    rec = r'(^|(?<=\n))[^\n\t]+\t[^\t]+(?=$|\n[^\n\t]+\t)'
    lol = [x.group().split('\t') for x in re.finditer(rec,data)]
```

or, if you prefer to replace newlines with blanks

```
    lol = [x.group().replace('\n',' ').split('\t') for x in re.finditer(rec,data)]
```